# how to change a static variable in broadcaster onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to get the sending status of each phone number, so I define a variable `statusMap` to record the status, 0 means success, 1 means failed. And I assign value to `statusMap` at `onReceive` function, but after that the statusMap's value is still empty. how can I change a static value in `onReceive` function

```
package com.mem.memsms;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Queue;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SendMessage extends Activity {
private EditText editText;
private Button button;
private Intent intent;
private SendBroadcast mSendReceiver;

private HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
private HashMap<String, String> statusMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
private Queue<String> numbers;
String SENT_SMS_ACTION = "SENT_SMS_ACTION";
String DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION = "DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_message);
    editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.message);
    intent = getIntent();
    hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
    numbers = new LinkedList<String>();

    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendmessage);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            numbers.clear();
            editText.setEnabled(false);
            final String text = editText.getText().toString();
            if (text.trim() == "") {
                editText.setHint(R.string.msg_null);
                return;
            }
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = hashMap.entrySet()
                    .iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String>) iter
                        .next();
                String number = entry.getKey();
                String content = entry.getValue();
                numbers.offer(number);
                Sendmsg(number, content + text);
            }
            intent.putExtra("data2", statusMap);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            //Log.i("msg", "statusMap length is" + statusMap.size());
            // back to contacts
            SendMessage.this.finish();
        }

    });

}

private class SendBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String n = numbers.poll();
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            Log.i("msg", "c:ok" + n);
            statusMap.put(n, "0");
            break;

        default:
            Log.i("msg", "c:failed" + n);
            statusMap.put(n, "1");
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.unregisterReceiver(mSendReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mSendReceiver = new SendBroadcast();
    IntentFilter mSendFilter = new IntentFilter(SENT_SMS_ACTION);
    this.registerReceiver(mSendReceiver, mSendFilter);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.send_message, menu);
    return true;
}

private void Sendmsg(String number, String content) {

    Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT_SMS_ACTION);
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sentIntent,
            0);
    //sentIntent.putExtra("status", statusMap);
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, content, sentPI, null);

}
}
```

Comment: onReceive is getting called??

Comment: hmmm, sure, it is a callback function.  and log can be printed there when I use Logcat

Comment: could anybody take a look at this? thx in advance!

Comment: try to check the size of statusMap in the last line of onReceive

Comment: Which static variable do you want to change?

Comment: I want to change the value statusMap. the size in onReceive is OK. I just try to call setResult in onPause function, but cannot transpose the data2 to previous activity

Comment: To be sure: you want to save data to statusMap in onReceive method and the when you back to the previous activity you want to pass this statusMap in Bundle?

Comment: check my ans it should work

Comment: If any response solved your problem, you should accept an answer in order to help people who have the same problem in the future

Comment: hi, sorry for my so late to give my bounty cause no coding abouts on my weekends.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
intent.putExtra("data2", statusMap);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        //Log.i("msg", "statusMap length is" + statusMap.size());
        // back to contacts
        SendMessage.this.finish();
```

code from onClick and put it in onReceive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String n = numbers.poll();
    switch (getResultCode()) {
    case RESULT_OK:
        Log.i("msg", "c:ok" + n);
        statusMap.put(n, "0");
        break;

    default:
        Log.i("msg", "c:failed" + n);
        statusMap.put(n, "1");
        break;
    }
    if(hashMap.size()==statusMap.size()){
        intent.putExtra("data2", statusMap);
        SendMessage.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        //Log.i("msg", "statusMap length is" + statusMap.size());
        // back to contacts
        SendMessage.this.finish();
   }
}
```

The problem was that the onClick event is completed first that is you call set result and finish this activity and then onReceive is getting called so by the time your map is updated result was already sent

Comment: if put such snippet in onReceive, the first time when onReceive is called, intent with statusMap will be sent out then finish. the statusMap will has only one element.

Comment: in onReceive just check if it was the last message

Comment: ya, this should be worked, if sometimes I just need to add new member in case RESULT_OK, this will not work. you answer works anyway here, is there any more general solution for this problem.

Comment: event for message sent comes after you set the result so this is right way. Also don't forget to accept the ans.

Comment: "You may award your bounty in 14 hours.", seems cannot give bounty now, I will give when I can

Comment: Sure Zuckonit glad to help :-)

Comment: can you award bounty now??

Comment: If any response solved your problem, you should accept an answer in order to help people who have the same problem in the future